# Microsoft.Graph.ServiceException: Code: methodNotAllowed

Tags: c#, .net-core, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c

I am getting 400 after sending the request below to my b2c tenant. see below for more details:

Microsoft.Graph.ServiceException: Code: methodNotAllowed
Message: The method is not supported for this URL.

I need to reset the user password, so I am following what is described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/passwordauthenticationmethod-resetpassword?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=csharp

here is my code:

```
public async Task<string> ResetPassword(string userId)
        {
            var newPassword = Helpers.PasswordHelper.GenerateNewPassword(4, 8, 4);
            var result = await graphClient
                .Users[userId]
                .Authentication.PasswordMethods["{passwordAuthenticationMethod-id}"]
                .ResetPassword(newPassword, null)
                .Request()
                .PostAsync();
            return result.NewPassword;
        }
```

The package I added to the project

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Graph.Auth" Version="1.0.0-preview.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Graph.Beta" Version="0.39.0-preview" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Identity.Client" Version="4.13.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="3.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="5.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Method Not Allowed is 405 :P

Comment: Is the user id a proper user id, not something weird? I suppose one explanation of what you're experiencing is that the api converts everything into an endpoint URI, substituting the user id into the path, and it ends up matching something that doesn't accept post. But just an idea.

Comment: Do you have the role 'global admin' or 'authentication admin' or 'privileged authentication admin' roles to your account which you are logging in with?

Comment: how's going? Has your issue got resolved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to make the Graph API call using the SDK work by assign the role `User Administrator` to my b2c application and also generate a secret so that you can use it to configure your C# application.

```
{
  "appSettings": {

    // MAKE SURE THESE REPRESENT YOUR TENANT SETTINGS
    "TenantId": "XXXXX.onmicrosoft.com",
    "AppId": "2a4c5942-7156-4fce-b524-XXXXXXXXX",
    "ClientSecret": "7746Dj-_h4rrK-XXXXXXXXXX",
  }
}
```

And the code to update the password is:

```
public async Task<string> UpdateUserPassword(string userId)
{
    var password = Helpers.PasswordHelper.GenerateNewPassword(4, 8, 4);
    var user = new User
    {
        Id = userId,
        PasswordProfile = new PasswordProfile
        {
            Password = password,
            ForceChangePasswordNextSignIn = false
        },
        PasswordPolicies = "DisablePasswordExpiration"

    };

    await graphClient
        .Users[userId]
        .Request()
        .UpdateAsync(user);

    return password;
}
```

However, I have set `ForceChangePasswordNextSignIn = false` the b2c doesn't ask the user to change the password after the first sign-in using it. If you set it to `true` I cannot sign-in. I am using a custom policy for sign-in/up. Any idea?

Comment: adding the user administrator role did the trick for me, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It is not recommended that using the Microsoft Graph Beta version:
[image]

If you want to change a user's password, you can try to use Microsoft Graph API to do it, just try the simple console app below:

```
    using Newtonsoft.Json;
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Net;
    using System.Net.Http;
    using System.Net.Http.Headers;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    
    namespace graphsdktest
    {
        class Program
        {
    
            public static async Task<string> GetAccessToken()
            {
    
                using (var client = new HttpClient())
                {
                    var clientId = "<app id>";
                    var clientSecret = "<app secret>";
                    var tenantID = "<tenant id>";
                    var adminUserName = "<b2c admin user account>";
                    var password = "<b2c admin user password>";
    
                    var tokenUrl = @"https://login.microsoftonline.com/" + tenantID + "/oauth2/v2.0/token";
                    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(tokenUrl);
                    
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                    
                    List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> postData = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
                    postData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type", "password"));
                    postData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_id", clientId));
                    postData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_secret", clientSecret));
                    postData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("scope", "openid"));
                    postData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("username", adminUserName));
                    postData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("password", password));
    
                    FormUrlEncodedContent requestBody = new FormUrlEncodedContent(postData);
                  
                    var request = await client.PostAsync(tokenUrl, requestBody).ConfigureAwait(false);
                    var response = await request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    var responseData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(response);
                  
                    return ((dynamic)responseData).access_token;
                }
            }
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                var accessToken = GetAccessToken().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    
                var userID = "<target user id>";
                var newPass = "<new password>";
    
                var requstURL = @"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/" + userID;
    
                var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(requstURL);
                httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
                httpWebRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
                httpWebRequest.Method = "PATCH";
    
                using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
                {
                string json = "{\"passwordProfile\":{\"forceChangePasswordNextSignIn\":false,\"password\":\"" + newPass + "\"}}";
    
                    streamWriter.Write(json);
                }
    
                var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
    
                //if code is 204 means request has been accepted, change password successfully
                Console.WriteLine((int)httpResponse.StatusCode);
            }
    }

}
```

Permissions you need to grand to your application:

[image]

For more about this API, see [this official doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http).

Comment: Will the user be able to change the password after sign-in with the new password?

Comment: If you want users to set their new password after login, you can set value of forceChangePasswordNextSignIn in json as true

Comment: Thanks a lot. It is something knew for me, and not sure where to find the right info to test the code you posted, so can you confirm if this is right? I will try to add a image

Comment: btw I cannot see the permissions you posted.